# Eclipse + Maven + maven-license-plugin

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, maven-plugin

I've added the `maven-license-plugin` to my maven project which is setup in Eclipse. Now that its configured, I'm unable to find a way to execute it. Can anyone explain to me how you run this in eclipse ? thanks.

pom.xml file.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.google.code.maven-license-plugin</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-license-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0</version>
    <configuration>
            <header>header.txt</header>
        </configuration>  
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>check</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>                   
  </plugin>
```

Right click the project, Run As shows options for Maven `assembly/build/clean/install/package/generate-sources/test/jar` -- i do not have any other options.

**Attempted:**

Setting up an external tool which I setup as `${maven_exec}` (configured in the preferences to be a String Substitution for `mvn.bat`) with parameters `license:format -Dyear=2011 -Demail=myaddress@mycompany.com`

**Result:**

```
Buildfile: C:\dev\dependencies\maven\bin\mvn.bat

BUILD FAILED
C:\dev\dependencies\maven\bin\mvn.bat:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
```

Comment: Why do you need that in eclipse? Don't you build your application from the command line for distribution purposes?

Comment: "Content is not allowed in prolog." is usually an XML parser error indicating some invalid XML right at the start of the file.  Is your pom OK?

Comment: @Thomas, deloyed artifacts are built by Hudson. I wanted to ensure all files were licensed and this allows me a central way to ensure each file has the correct, most up to date license information - still not working though :)

Comment: @Matthew, thanks but unable to find a way around the issue. It would the plugin.

Comment: So you said, running the plugin from hudson doesn't work too? Did you set up hudson to call the `check` goal?

Comment: @user815809, on a sidenote, you would like to use a more recent version. Using Eclipse's plugin management wizard, look for               _com.mycila.maven-license-plugin_ groupId, same artifactId, most recent version being 1.10.b1.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](http://code.google.com/p/maven-license-plugin/wiki/HowTo), the check goal binds by default to the verify stage of the [maven build life cycle](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html).

> the default lifecycle has the following build phases (for a complete
>   list of the build phases, refer to the Lifecycle Reference):
>
> - validate - validate the project is correct and all necessary information is available
> - compile - compile the source code of the project
> - test - test the compiled source code using a suitable unit testing framework. These tests should not require the code be packaged or
>     deployed
> - package - take the compiled code and package it in its distributable format, such as a JAR.
> - integration-test - process and deploy the package if necessary into an environment where integration tests can be run
> - verify - run any checks to verify the package is valid and meets quality criteria
> - install - install the package into the local repository, for use as a dependency in other projects locally
> - deploy - done in an integration or release environment, copies the final package to the remote repository for sharing with other
>     developers and projects.

So you will need to run a build phase that has *verify* as a predecessor i.e. *install* or *deploy*.
Install is available on the maven run menu as you indicated above.
You select "run as > maven build ..." you will be prompted for which goal to execute where you can directly specify *verify*, and save this as a run configuration called project-verify.

Alternatively you can bind the check goal to a different life cycle phase, check the documentation link above for this config.

Answer (score 0):

The plugin has the following goals:

- `check` (as seen [here](http://code.google.com/p/maven-license-plugin/source/browse/branches/maven-license-plugin-1.x.x/src/main/java/com/google/code/mojo/license/LicenseCheckMojo.java))
- `format` (as seen [here](http://code.google.com/p/maven-license-plugin/source/browse/branches/maven-license-plugin-1.x.x/src/main/java/com/google/code/mojo/license/LicenseFormatMojo.java))
- `remove` (as seen [here](http://code.google.com/p/maven-license-plugin/source/browse/branches/maven-license-plugin-1.x.x/src/main/java/com/google/code/mojo/license/LicenseRemoveMojo.java))

Perhaps in Eclipse you could set these goals to run, but I would personally suggest running them through a console.

Answer (score 0):

Select your project and then chose Run as and select `build...` and then type your goals

for example in your case you can do :

```
license:check
license:format
license:remove
```